# custom Google Maps location dot

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'm been looking around for an interesting way to display a Google Maps onto my contact page and I've found something very interesting, but I can't seem to figure out how it's been done. I've seen it on a website ([see original page here](http://www.pheromone.ca/fr/contact)).

[image]

As you can see if you view the page, the map is interactive and the dot follows, which is very neat. I can't seem to find how this is customizable. What's more interesting is that it is quite responsive (although seems to flicker in Firefox 24 for mac).

Would this be some kind of absolute position relative to the dot, some jQuery, some mystical Google Maps eye candy tool that they seem to hide well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no magic to it, this is just a [custom google maps marker image](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#icons). The only thing you have to do is specify an image path in the marker options when you initialize your marker like you do normally:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: latlngPosition,
  map: map,
  icon: 'path/to/image'
});
```

For more reference on other marker options you can set, click [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerOptions).